# Authorize.Net pingback to my site

Tags: authorize.net

I am using Authorize.Net ARB for paid membership. I am not sure, how to know when recurring payment has been cancelled (or something else) and I should disable the account.

The only one thing I have found is a Silent Post functionality, but not all transactions post a respose with Silent Post.

Is there any other way my script can be notified about all transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Silent Post is the only way to know about the status of recurring billing transactions from ARB.</s> You can use the ARBGetSubscriptionStatusRequest API call to get the status of any subscription so that should do what you need.

Authorize.Net has since added [Webhooks](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/webhooks.html) which can tell you about a lot of events including those related to ARB. You can now be notified of the following events:

- net.authorize.customer.subscription.cancelled
- net.authorize.customer.subscription.created
- net.authorize.customer.subscription.expiring
- net.authorize.customer.subscription.suspended
- net.authorize.customer.subscription.terminated
- net.authorize.customer.subscription.updated

Once you receive the webhook notification you can react the the event accordingly using existing ARB API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Webhooks](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/webhooks.html) is the preferred method over Silent post. 
Specifically, in this case, the following events:

- net.authorize.customer.subscription.terminated
- net.authorize.customer.subscription.cancelled
- net.authorize.customer.subscription.expiring